# Unwanted SharePoint context menu

Tags: sharepoint

I created a custom lookup field type which works fine. However, there is a context menu for every item in columns of this type.

[image: the unwanted SharePoint drop-down menu]

I **didn't do anything on purpose** to add this context menu.

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The source list "Cities" had three columns - "Name of the city", "Name of the city (linked to item)" and "Name of the city (linked to item with edit menu)".
When I was creating the "medium city" column in the "Customers" list, I chose "Name of the city" from the drop-down list. I was positive it was the 1st column but it turned out it was the 3rd one.
I modified the code filling the drop-down list with data so it contains no *linked to item* columns and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `View` -> `Modify this View`, you can select from the fields you'd like to have visible in the default view. There should be several options for some fields, and the one you likely have by default will be something like `medium city (linked to document with edit menu)`. Choose `medium city` on its own and you should be good to go!

Comment: I know about this, there are 3 versions of the "Title" field but "medium city" is a custom lookup column and it doesn't work like this.